# Asking for proof verification of a theorem in Apostol Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am self studying Apostol Mathematical Analysis Ch-> Lebesgue integration and I have a different thinking about a proof whose only outline is given in Apostol Book.

It's image is ->

[image]

In part (a) when Apostol writes $g \in L(I+c)$ and in proof Apostol gives First verify theorem for step functions, then upper functions and then Lebesgue-integrable functions.

But I thought as $f \in L(I)$ and $g(x) = f(x-c)$ for $x \in I+c$. So,using it $g \in L(I+c)$ as $f \in I$ can be written as difference of upper functions and using the note I can derive the integral relations in all 3 cases (which I have done in note book).

> But I never used any of verification on step functions, then for upper functions and finally Lebesgue-integrable functions.

So, am I right in my approach? and if not kindly tell the right way to prove it.

Comment: I think your argument is for Riemann integrable functions and Apostol's argument is for Lebesgue integrals. The latter is defined through simple functions so his approach is the right one.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Ok!!