# A question in proof of Apostol ( Mathematical Analysis) in Theorem 10.27

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am self studying Apostol Mathematical Analysis Chapter->Lebesgue Integration and I was unable to think about an argument used in that proof.

Adding it's image ->[image]

> Can someone please tell a rigorous argument which deduces the blue underlined portion of the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G_{n,1}(x)=\max \{f_1(x),f_2(x),...,f_n(x)\}$. The right hand side is increasing and its limit is $\sup \{f_n(x): n=1,2...\}$. Also $G_{n,1}(x) \to G_1(x)$ almost everywhere. Hence you only have to take limit as $n \to \infty$ to get $G_1(x)=\sup \{f_1(x),f_2(x),...\}$ almost everywhere.

Comment: can you please have a look at this question asked by me if you have some spare time? No one has answered it till now. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724527/asking-for-proof-verification-of-a-theorem-in-apostol-mathematical-analysis